# woocommerce variation displaying all option even if it's not related to that variantion

Tags: wordpress

Hello,

I have 2 variation in woocommerce first is series and second is name like this:

```
Series :  and Name :
```

in Series two type of Series A and B
in Name lots of names

```
Series :     Name:
A            ANNN1,ANNN2,ANNN3
B            BMMM1,BMMM2,BMMM3
```

Like you can See A-Name is related to A series and B-Name to B series

But when see product page Name: variation shows all option 
Even I choose Series A or B

```
ANNN1
ANNN2
ANNN3
BMMM1
BMMM2
BMMM3
```

So what I should I do to show specific Name to related that Series Like this

If I choose Series A

```
Series: A
Name: ANNN1
      ANNN2
      ANNN3
```

If I choose Series B

```
Series : B
Name :BMMM1
      BMMM2
      BMMM3
```

Comment: Check this answer over here, it seems to be the same as yours.
[Dependent Product Variations in Woocommerce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630229/dependent-product-variations-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Thnx for reply But it's not same

Comment: would you mind to explain the difference between your case and the case for this guy? that way i might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin and scroll down where it says "Set dependency between the options"

https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-product-add-ons/

You can even test out the features before buying by going on to this website http://plugins.yithemes.com/yith-woocommerce-product-add-ons/product/custom-post/ and using the top botton for launching admin demo